# If $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+1}$, then $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+m}$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $f: V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation, with $V$ being a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F$, such that $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+1}$, then  $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+m}$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$.

We prove by induction on $m$. If $m =1$, this is clearly true.

Now, assume it is true for $m=n$ and we show that it is true for $m=n+1$. Thus we need to show that $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+n+1}$.

Is it correct to say that since $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+1}$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$, then $\ker f^{k+n}$ = $\ker f^{k+n+1}$, hence $\ker f^k = \ker f^{k+n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, for $n$ is fixed.

Comment: No, what is given is that for some fixed $k$, we have: ker $f^k$ = ker $f^{k+1}$.

Comment: OK, @Aravind, what can I do to fix my proof?

Comment: Use the definition of kernel?!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the inductive step:

Suppose $\ker f^{k+n}=\ker f^k$ for some $n>0$.

$\ker f^k\subset \ker f^{k+n+1}$ is trivial. To prove the reverse inclusion, let $x\in\ker f^{k+n+1}$. So $f(x)\in\ker f^{k+n}$. By the inductive hypothesis, $f(x)\in\ker f^k$, i.e. $x\in\ker f^{k+1}=\ker f^k$ (initial step). The inductive step is proved.